# Reactive power doesn't add up in load flow analysis

Tags: power, load

I am doing a load flow analysis as part of my coursework in MATPOWER and need help figuring out the mathematics behind the bus data in the third table below. Basically, the three generators' real power equals the real power consumed by the load, plus the loss. However, the reactive powers don't add up in the table. There's some loss in reactive power as well, but even if I add it with the reactive power consumed by the load, it wouldn't equal reactive power generated by the generators. Everything would make sense however if I take "Branch Charging (inj)" of 140.5 from the first table into account. But I'm not sure where its coming from or what it is at all. It is my assumption that the reactive power needed by the load is generated by the generators only. I would appreciate any help in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Branch #7 seems to have a large phase offset. (6 deg)

Comment: Could you please explain how that affects reactive power?

Comment: When branch phases are not in sync but same voltage, then the vector power transfer is the difference and Impedance between them,  If they are in sync but different voltage, then real power is transferred.  But I am not familiar with your software.